# access google web search from java

Tags: java, search-engine, google-api

since SOAP has been stopped, is there any way i can access google web search from java.
I searched for google APIs but currently it provides JSON which is java script.

But i want to access from JAVA not javascript.i would like to know if there is any way to do so?

Comment: JSON is not necessarily javascript, it is simply JavaScript Object Notation...there are libraries that read JSON in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse JSON with Java.  For instance, check out [the XStream tutorial on parsing JSON](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

use JSONObject and JSONArray and Apache Http. I have written a tutorial to get xml/json from REST and am now in the process of posting how to parse it using JSONObjects/JSONArrays. I will have the JSON tutorial up later tonight but here is a [REST Tutorial](http://ericosgood.com/2011/01/rest-webservice-android/) it currently has JSONArray parsing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the incoming JSON text and convert to Java object graph.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) may work for you. You will need to create Custom Search Engine with no sites that will fall back to Google Search. Haven't tried this though.